# How to load image in sama5d27-som1-ek board using dataflash

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I want to load image using dataflash in place of SD-card.what changes in bootstrap folder are required to do so.how can i copy u-boot in RAM using data flash.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dataflash on the sama5d27-som1-ek but if you meant you want to use the qspi flash, then simply use *sama5d27_som1_ekqspi_uboot_defconfig* to configure at91bootstrap, as stated in [the instructions to build from source](https://www.linux4sam.org/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage#Build_From_source_code). This configures at91bootstrap to load u-boot from flash instead of SD card. Don't forget to use *sama5d27_som1_ek_qspiflash_defconfig* to configure u-boot.

Comment: Thank you. i will try it